# How do I get my for loop to replace these words in a T-SQL query in python?

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I'm still new to Python and am learning new things everyday, but I keep running into issues that I'm not finding answers for online, despite being simple problems.

I'm simply trying to run through a loop so I don't have to repeat the same multiple queries with just one different word for each one.

I've tried setting a variable named

```
assets = ["AT", "AST", "PAC", "AC"]
```

I tried using

```
for i in range(4)
for i in assets
```

and a few more examples, but i keep getting the error Invalid column name 'i'

Which is obvious why, because it's not going through the array or vector like i would like it to.

```
assets = ["AT", "AST", "PAC", "AC"]
i = 0
for i in assets:

    q1 = """\
SELECT 'UnC' AS [i], SUM(CASE WHEN [i] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [i 
Count]
    FROM SM.dbo.vSC SCL
        JOIN IP.dbo.vSLUN(3) S
            ON SCL.iSID=S.isID
        JOIN SMa.dbo.S_C SC(noLock) ON S.isID=SC.iSID
WHERE SC.bIsInA IS NULL AND [i] IS NULL"""

df1 = pd.read_sql(q1, conn)
print(df1)
```

I would like to achieve running 4 different queries with the names changing after each query is finished being stored in a variable, which I would eventually like to print out the results with, for each query. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, you cannot interpolate strings in the manner you attempted, specifically embedding a value directly in another string body which may be possible in other langauges (PHP, Perl, etc.).

Usually in Python, placeholders and binded values are used. While there are multiple ways to interpolate strings in Python (>=2.6), the preferred universal way is with [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). Since you need to format the same value, place all with first ordinal position, `{0}`:

```
for i in assets: 
    q1 = """SELECT 'UnC' AS [{0}], SUM(CASE WHEN [{0}] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [{0} Count]
            FROM SM.dbo.vSC SCL
            JOIN IP.dbo.vSLUN(3) S
                ON SCL.iSID = S.isID
            JOIN SMa.dbo.S_C SC(noLock) ON S.isID = SC.iSID
            WHERE SC.bIsInA IS NULL AND [{0}] IS NULL
         """

    q1 = q1.format(i)

    df1 = pd.read_sql(q1, conn)
```

Comment: I was able to run the query using what you've suggested, but my biggest issue is not being able to run through the loop to the next index in the array. I would like to run the query for all 4 in assets please. i tried assets[0:4], but i'm clearly missing something, should i change the {0} to {0:4} ?

Comment: Do you want to create four separate data frames? This should loop and give a different result of *df1* for each pass. Check with `df1.head()` (indented inside `for` loop).

Comment: @idcny please see my comment above in the first answer. I'm 99% sure you're only seeing the last one because your print function is not inside your loop

Answer (score 1):

Write your query for example like this:

```
q1 = """\

  SELECT *REPLACETHIS* FROM whatever;
```

Then say

```py
for i in assets:
  print(q1.replace("*REPLACETHIS*", i))
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I didn't understand at first until i just ran what you said, once i saw the results, i was able to figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: I seem to be running into another problem now, it only prints the last one in the array "AC". It doesn't print 4 query results like i was hoping. If i put print(x) before the query q1, it print all 4 items. after the query, only the last one. Any idea?

Comment: @idcny are you sure everything is tabbed in the way it should be? I know it's hard to show in markdown here, but if the `print` isn't indented inside the loop, it'll only do the last element

Answer (score 0):

```
assets = ["AT", "AST", "PAC", "AC"]

x = 0
for x in assets[0:4]:

    q1 = """\
SELECT 'Unc' AS [x], SUM(CASE WHEN [x] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [x 
Count]
    FROM SM.dbo.vSC SCL
        JOIN IP.dbo.vSLUNode(3) S
            ON SCL.iSID=S.isID
        JOIN SM.dbo.S_C SC ON 
S.isID=SC.iSID
WHERE SC.bIIA IS NULL AND [x] IS NULL"""


print(q1.replace("x", x))






 assets = ["AT", "AST", "PAC", "AC"]


for i in assets[0:4]:

    q1 = """\
SELECT 'Unc' AS [{0}], SUM(CASE WHEN [{0}] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [{0} Count]
    FROM SM.dbo.vSC SCL
        JOIN IP.dbo.vSLUNode(3) S
            ON SCL.iSID=S.isID
        JOIN SM.dbo.S_C SC ON 
S.isID=SC.iSID
WHERE SC.bIIA IS NULL AND [{0}] IS NULL"""


q1 = q1.format(i)
df1 = pd.read_sql(q1, conn)
print(df1)
```